# Convert Usd to Ethereum

Tags: ethereum

I Want a php code for Usd To Ethereum Conversation. Like This code:

```
<?php
$url = "https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=2000";
$stats = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo "$stats BTC";
?>
```

I Can't find in any websites, please help me.

Comment: The response is not a JSON, just drop the `json_decode`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
GET https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR

{"BTC":0.02483,"USD":257.31,"EUR":237}
```